# "Can't assign to array" compile error

Tags: vba

I am new to VBA , When I execute below function , am getting "Can't assign to array" compile error

```
Function GetPriorities() As String()

    Dim wksMapping As Worksheet
    Dim LastRowMapping As Long
    Dim cnt As Long
    Dim cntIndex As Long

    cntIndex = 0
    LastRowMapping = Worksheets(MAPPING).Cells(Worksheets(MAPPING).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
ReDim arrHighPriority(LastRowMapping - 2)

    For cnt = 2 To LastRowMapping
      arrHighPriority(cntIndex) = Worksheets(MAPPING).Cells(cnt, 2).Value
      cntIndex = cntIndex + 1
    Next cnt

    GetPriorities = arrHighPriority

End Function
```

My requirement is to call above function and assign the array returned by function to a variable.

My  code for calling above function is

```
Dim x() As String    
x = GetPriorities
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the array so it can match the returned type:

```
Function GetPriorities() As String()

    Dim wksMapping As Worksheet
    Dim arrHighPriority() As String

    ...

    GetPriorities = arrHighPriority

End Function
```

Comment: OK , so in my case , it should be ReDim arrHighPriority(LastRowMapping - 2) as string. right  ?

Comment: There's no need, once it's been declared it can't be changed with redim.